# Android Shared Storage Open Picture inside own App

Tags: java, android, storage, storage-access-framework

im just wondering. Wasnt it declared by devs that to open media files in shared storage, who comes from another app, need to declare permission in Manifest?

Like why is this code working without any permissions? I can open nearly every picture in shared storage i have on my phone and use it inside my owner app.

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            activityResultLauncher.launch(intent);
        }
    });


} 

ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> activityResultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(), new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
        Uri uri = result.getData().getData();
        imageView.setImageURI(uri);
    }
});
```

Comment: ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT does indeed not need any permission. And it has nothing to do 
with media files as the user can select any type of file. From device storage, external drive and cloud. And you did not even tell which permission you have in mind.

Comment: Okay i searched a little bit further and now i see that its possible to use the MediaStore API or the Storage Access Framewrok SAF for reaching Data in the shared storage. The example above shows, that its possible to read a MediaFile with the SAF. So now i want to know what is the benefit of MediaStore API? When do i have to use it instead of SAF?

Comment: You cann do what you want and you will know that a difference for instance is that with SAF you need user interaction. With media store not.